# Can't find "People" category in Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com, contacts

I'm unable to find the "People" (formerly called Contacts) icon on my Mail Page of the new Outlook.com . My friends say there should be a little check to click on at the top left hand side of the page (just to the right of the word Outlook), but it is NOT there. Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Not there? Is this true in all browsers? Are you logged in?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the main menu by clicking the down arrow next to "Outlook"

   [image: outlook logo]
2. Select the "People" app

   [image: main menu]